# Eclipse not giving suggestions for java.awt.Color

Tags: java, eclipse, colors

This may be a dumb question, but I do not know what to do. I write Java applications as a hobby, so I don´t have a deep understanding how Eclipse works. Until the last time I ran Eclipse, it was able to give me suggestions on all common classes that I´m used to. But now it doesn´t give me suggestions for importing java.awt.Color (figure 1). If I write the import manually, it doesn´t give me suggestions for the instantiation (figure 2). If I create a Color object, it doesn´t give me suggestions for Color methods (figure 3)..

I tried to Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Content Assist->Advanced and check all options. Doesn´t work. What can I do?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved after Window > Preferences > Java > Appearance > Type Filters and uncheck all.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward and informative to me, because his answer turned out to be helpful for me, at least.